# Different Format for values in column VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys im facing a little issue. My Code calculate some values based on specific values from other rows and column. Those rows and columns are formated in specific format, background etc so i just use below code to copy formating from one column to other.

In original formating (generated by external system) lets stay negative values are in () and have red color. Problem is that when i copy formating from that column and my calculations are positive they are formated like negative (() and red color) is there any possibility to format "conditionaly"? without using for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You can use `yourRange.Interior.Color = RGB(a;b;c)`, you can also you `yourRange.NumberFormat = ...` ..

You can use an If to test the value before..

Comment: By the way, if you want to copy the whole parameters of a cell, you can use `Range(..).Copy` and then `Range(...).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormat`

Comment: What i do is`.Column(1).copy` then `Column(2).paste xlpasteformats` and if in same row that Column1 has negative numer, and i have positive number formating from negative is copied. i know i can loop thru all of my cells in that column and fix formating but i just wonder is there method to do that without looping

Comment: I've been thinking of something like : filter the positive values of your Column(2), apply the positive format to the visible cells, make all cells visible, filter the negative values, apply the negative format to the visible cells, make all cells visible. But it's, on my opinion, a little bit weaker than iterate through your column(2)

Comment: Im just trying to optimize execution speed and i sometimes in my files i have like 5-10 additional columns (which need formatting) and 40 000 - 60 000 row. You still belive lopp would be better?

Comment: Try both and compare the execution time. `Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
  StartTime = Timer
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 4)`  .

If you want a sample of code of what my idea looks like, please tell me ! :)

Comment: I can handle it myself but thanks! ;]